# Why test accuracy remains constant and do not increase in binary classification when test and train dataset are from different source

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, classification, deep-learning, theano

I have ***train*** dataset and ***test*** dataset from two different sources. I mean they are from two different experiments but the results of both of them are same biological images. I want to do binary classification using ***deep CNN*** and I have following results on test accuracy and train accuracy. The blue line shows train accuracy and the red line shows test accuracy after almost *250* epochs. Why the test accuracy is almost constant and not raising?  Is that because ***Test*** and ***Train*** dataset are come from different distributions?[image]

Edited:
After I have add dropout layer, reguralization terms and mean subtraction I still get following strange results which says the model is overfitting from the beginning!

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4):

There could be 2 reasons. First you overfit on the training data. This can be validated by using the validation score as a comparison metric to the test data. If so you can use standard techniques to combat overfitting, like weight decay and dropout.

The second one is that your data is too different to be learned like this. This is harder to solve. You should first look at the value spread of both images. Are they both normalized. Matplotlib normalizes automatically for plotted images. If this still does not work you might want to look into augmentation to make your training data more similar to the test data. Here I can not tell you what to use, without seeing both the trainset and the testset.

Edit:

For normalization the test set and the training set should have a similar value spread. If you do dataset normalization you calculate mean and std on training set. But you also need to use those calculated values on the test set and not calculate the test set values from the test set. This only makes sense if the value spread is similar for both the training and test set. If this is not the case you might want to do per sample normalization first.

Other augmentation that are commonly used for every dataset are oversampling, random channel shifts, random rotations, random translation and random zoom. This makes you invariante to those operations.

Comment: Yes exactly work on the data augmentation part. That is the key to a good machine learning model.

Comment: I'm doing normalization by mean subtraction for the train dataset using the mean and standard deviation values. I perform following procedure
    
    scaled_train =  (train - train_mean) / train_std_deviation

What else I can do for data augmentation?
    scaled_test = (test - train_mean) / train_std_deviation

Comment: Edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks @ThomasPinetz! I have shuffled data, I did mean subtraction, I have added dropout layer to my CNN, I added regularizer as well! But still the training loss decrease whereas the validation loss increases and its accuracy increases as well. I don't know why the test loss decrease though! I don't have any idea how to deal with this problem!

Comment: Your validation loss increases? Loss should be decreasing. Anyways plot yourself images from the validation set with the colorbar enabled and from the test set with the colorbar enabled. This often gives additional insights.

Comment: I have edited and add loss and error plots! it shows from the beginning there is overfitting problem!